# Devise mass assignment error for failed logins when using username as login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

HAving a weird one.

I've set up devise to authenticate using either a username or an email as per 
[Devise login with username](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

I can log in absolutely fine with a correct username or email with a password. 
If I put something incorrect in, I get a

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: login
```

Can't work out quite what's going on. I assume it's something to do with Devise killing the session, but not sure why it would be doing anything with the login field at that point....

Comment: Please post your model and controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model please add login to `attr_accessible`, i.e;

```
attr_accessible :login .
```

For more info, refer to this;
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible